# How to Use extensions as API in python code

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to use Chrome Extension in Python 3.4 code? I tried some google searching but not able to find the correct information.

Comment: Generally no. Extensions are written in JavaScript and browsers can't run python code directly. However your actual goal may have a solution so it'd make sense to describe what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: There is an extension named "Media Bias Fact Check" which classify articles in bias , least bias and in much more classes I have some articles to classify in my private pc I goal was to code in python and use this extension in my code

Comment: I think it's possible by using a [chrome remote debugging library](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+chrome+remote+debugging+library) to control Chrome including the extension which is installed in the browser. Look for tutorials and examples.

Comment: do you have any tutorial's link?